# How to pass all flags in a Powershell New-Alias?

Tags: powershell

I'm using `C:\Users\User\Documents\Powershell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` for some alias commands for my every day work.

Example:

```
function MyAliasCommand { .\custom\script.ps1 }
New-Alias my MyAliasCommand
```

It works if I call it from my Powershell using the command "my".

I'm happy.

What it doesn't work is if I need to pass flags to `my`, example:

`my -d one`

How to do this?

Is there a way to let powershell pass all my arguments in the `function MyAliasCommand`?

Something like: `function MyAliasCommand { .\custom\script.ps1 $allTheFlags }`?

Comment: So it's a an alias to a function, that calls on a *.ps1*? Looking at this alone, if your *.ps1* accepts parameter input, your function doesn't. Unless I'm reading this wrong, you will need to parameterize your function that'll essentially pass the same parameters to your script.

Comment: Looking at this, *again*, you should be able to create an alias directly to the *.ps1*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this as follows:
`./custom/script.ps1`

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter()]
    [string]
    $d
)

Write-Host $d
```

Then you can write:

```
function MyCommand {
    & $PSScriptRoot/custom/script.ps1 @args
}

New-Alias myAlias MyCommand

myAlias -d 'one'
```

Take into account that I used the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#call-operator-) and [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.1).

`$args` will contain all the parameters you supply.

Comment: Yep. It works. Can you help me with this too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69423149/how-to-execute-node-js-file-with-powershell-without-node-before-the-name